# Send NSString in AFMultipartFormData without using encoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, multipartform-data

I'm uploading images and other media on server using `AFMultipartFormData` which was uploading fine. But the backend structure requires me to send a string value with every file that I upload.

```
for(NSData *eachImage in dataStringArray) {

            NSString *mystring = [dataTypeArray objectAtIndex:[dataStringArray indexOfObject:eachImage]];

            NSLog(@"%@, %@",mystring,[mystring dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);

            NSURLRequest *request = [manager.requestSerializer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:string parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

                [formData appendPartWithFormData:eachImage name:@"myImage"];
                [formData appendPartWithFormData:[mystring dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]
                                            name:@"FileDesc"];


            } error:&error];
```

Now suppose `myString` is `@"0"` so the `NSASCIIStringEncoding` converts it to `<30>` but I just want `0` there. how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can pass additional parameter with file as below :

```
NSURLRequest *request = [manager.requestSerializer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@{@"FileDesc": mystring} parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

                [formData appendPartWithFormData:eachImage name:@"myImage"];



            } error:&error];
```